# failed to authorize twitter when trying to authorize app with windows phone 8/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, twitter, windows-phone-8.1, twitter-oauth

I've got a windows phone 8/8.1 app which contains a page with an embedded web browser on it. I build a list of articles extracting information from the website and all of this works fine but note that I only use this web browser to display an article when a user has clicked on the item in my list.

The article in question provides a button to allow user to leave comments via twitter. At the bottom of each article there is a "Twitter Log in" button. When I click on it, it brings me to the authorizing page and it displays the news website as the app I want to authorize.

After entering my twitter credential and clicking on the "Authorize App", I get the following error:

`Exception of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserNavigationException' was thrown.`

Then a Twitter webpage gets displayed display the following:

`There is no request token for this page. That's a special key we need from applications asking you to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again. It's probably just a mistake.`

It definitely authenticated me as I can see my Twitter account picture but it failed to authorize the app.

I understand that my app is not the original website as it is a wp8/8.1 app but what I'm calling in the web browser is the page that contains all the original code from the news website and therefore you would assume everything would work as if I was calling the website directly from a browser.

If I call the website from the browser that comes with wp8/8.1, it works as expected!! Strangely enough they have the same functionality but using facebook and this works as expected.

I've had a look at `html` the "twitter authorized page" when called from my phone and when called directly from my web browser on my laptop and while I can clearly see the form contains an hidden field for `authenticity_token` with a value and a `oauth_token` with another value, they do differ.

I don't know if they're suppose to be identical but as I said, I don't understand why this wouldn't work as when I display the article in the embedded web browser, you'd assume that everything else that goes on after this would behave as it would in a regular web browser and when this 'authorize app' button is clicked, you'd assume that all values would be passed as normal and the app would get authorized but nope!!

Any suggestions on how I could possible resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what's going on, but it looks like you would have to implement Twitter OAuth. Luckily for you there is already a library that can do that - https://github.com/konradbartecki/TwitterAutherino

I am the author of this library, so let me know if you need some support or non-existent features.